Binding Events and Functions to Dynamic Components in Vue 3
I have an array of form field like below and I wanna render dynamic form with event and function
[...{
            label: "Logo",
            field: "image",
            component: SingleImg,
            event:"select",
            handleEvent:(event) => {
                console.log("hello")
            },
            attributes: {
              upload:false,
              type: "file",
              accept: "image/*",
              maxFileSize: 10000000,
              showUploadButton: false,
              showCancelButton: false,
              
            },
          },]


here is how I render:
<component
              :is="row.component"
              v-bind="row.attributes"
              v-model="formData[row.field]"
              :key="row.field"
              @[row.event]="row.handleEvent"
            ></component>

How can I correctly bind events and their corresponding functions to dynamic components in Vue 3?
Can anyone tell me how to render events and function properly in Vue template

Have you tried with v-on attribute for event?

change you config like below sample:
 on: {
            keyDown: (event) => {
            console.log("hello")
        }
    },

And use v-on in the component:
 <component
          :is="row.component"
          v-bind="row.attributes"
          v-model="formData[row.field]"
          :key="row.field"
          v-on="row.on"
        ></component>

